# Tikz forest diagram displaced to top and right

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

I am creating what seems like a straightforward tree using tikz and forest. The figure is close to what I want, but appears significantly to the left and right of the expected place, outside the bounds of the figure and even the page.

[image: tree rendering top right]

The "1" next to the top node is page numbering.

Code example:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path,positioning,shapes,calc,arrows.meta,graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{forest}

\def\choicep{\times}
\def\seqop{\rightarrow}

\begin{document}

Introductory text.

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={ellipse,draw},
                        sibling distance=2pt]
        \begin{forest}
        for tree={
            edge = {->},
            ellipse,
            draw,
            math content,
            anchor = center
        },
        [\choicep:4
            [\seqop:1
                [a:1]
                [b:1]
            ]
            [\seqop:1
                [a:1]
                [b:1]
            ]
            [\seqop:1
                [b:1]
                [a:1]
            ]
            [\seqop:1
                [c:1]
                [c:1]
                [c:1]
            ]
        ]
        \end{forest}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Misaligned tree (skews top right).}
    \label{fig:discovery-eg-trace}
\end{figure}

Closing text.

\end{document}
```

This is an MRE, but I found the behaviour originally within a subfigure, with surrounding text, etc. It happily plonks itself over other text, figures, page headers etc. I am using overleaf.

Seems like it should be something basic but has me scratching my head. I also tried `\graph` and the `{}` syntax, but that choked on the mathematical symbols for the nodes.

Comment: `forest` environment is already a `tikzpicture` therefore your code nest tikzpictures which is not recommended. if you delete the `tikzpicture` environment, the `forest` diagram will go to their place.

Comment: That was it. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments.

Comment: The answer was both useful and non-obvious to me. I'm neither LaTeX newbie nor guru. So I have copied to an answer, but marked as a community wiki.

Comment: @AdamBurke You did well, I voted to leave open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `forest` environment is already a `tikzpicture`, therefore your code nests `tikzpicture`s, which is not recommended. if you delete the `tikzpicture` environment, the `forest` diagram will go to their place.

(From @Ignasi in the comments.)